# How to tidy this dataset?

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

I have the dataset below that I want to tidy up.

```
     user_id                topic may june july august september october
1     192775                 talk   2    0    0      2         2       1
2     192775                 walk 165  123  128    146       113     105
3     192775                 bark   0    0    0      0         0       0
4     192775                 harp   0    0    0      0         0       1
```

I want to use tidyr to shape into the below format.

```
user_id      month      talk      walk      bark      harp
192775       may           2       165         0         0
192775      june           0       123         0         0
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% gather(month, val, may:october) %>% spread(topic, val)
```

you get:

> ```
>   user_id     month bark harp talk walk
> 1  192775    august    0    0    2  146
> 2  192775      july    0    0    0  128
> 3  192775      june    0    0    0  123
> 4  192775       may    0    0    2  165
> 5  192775   october    0    1    1  105
> 6  192775 september    0    0    2  113
> ```

---

Another option is to use `recast` from the `reshape2`-package:

```
library(reshape2)
recast(df, user_id + variable ~ topic, id.var = c('user_id','topic'))
```